# How to perform data replication for DBs on multi-server Docker Container setup?

Tags: mysql, docker

[image: Setup Sketch]

For setting up Disaster Recovery topology using docker, is it possible to perform data replication from one server to another without using any orchestration layer (swarm/Kubernetes)?
Any way to setup MySQL Master-Master or Master-Slave on 2 server setup?

What I do NOT want:

1. Data replication using shared disk space
2. No third party tool/software
3. No Swarm or Kubernetes

I understand that for a proper Disaster Recovery system, the standby system is recommended to be in a totally different region, and it's acceptable that there is delay in data replication. What I want to know is will the both docker containers be able to communicate with each other properly? Is there anything that needs to be configured? Or will they just communicate normally as it would have been without docker?

Comment: Note that replication will not protect you from disasters and data loss events that are propagated over your replication mechanism (an erroneous or malicious but valid  SQL statement is but one scenario) you will probably still need a more conventional backup scenario as well depending on your RTO and RPO ‘s

Comment: You need an overlay network so that the two containers can communicate with each other. A search for *docker overlay network without swarm* yields results, for example https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2018/01/03/revisit-setting-up-an-overlay-network-on-docker-without-docker-swarm/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two db servers, physically close to each other, will achieve the goal.

- There will still be some lag from the Primary to the Replica, but probably less than 1ms.
- The Replica won't start performing a replicated query until it has COMMITted on the Primary.  (This is another mandatory lag.)  As long as your writes affect only a small number of rows, this is also sub-millisecond or low-milliseconds.
- If Master-Master, each is allowed to receive writes, and each is both a "master" and a "slave".  However, I recommend only writing to one at a time; the other is simply a hot standby.
- M-M is M-S already set up in both directions, hence allows for simplified failover.
- Whether each db server is actually inside a Docker container should not matter.
- But having two separate machines provides DR, whereas two Dockers in a single server does not protect against motherboard, disk, etc, failures.
- The pieces for failover is part of the standard issue MySQL/MariaDB, but the performing a failover is still manual.
- If one of the two machines fails, you need to take some non-trivial effort (and time) to rebuild the other machine.
- Two machines in the same flood plain, earthquake fault, tornado alley, etc. -- For real DR, you need geographic separation.  But that leads to latency between servers.  Can't have everything!

See also Galera Cluster (shipped with MariaDB; or can be added to MySQL).  With it, 3 "nodes", one per server, gives automatic failover and automatic repair.

As far as I know, Docker does not introduce any extra impediments. Maybe someone else will chime in.  If there are multiple MySQL instances in multiple dockers, then there is an issue of getting the Port numbers separate.

PS.  dba.stackoverflow.com is a better sight for MySQL/MariaDB questions.

Comment: This answer is explaining more of what DR is, which is not being asked. I understand that for a proper DR system, the standby system is recommended to be in a totally different region, and it's acceptable that there is delay in data replication.

What I want to know is will the both docker containers be able to communicate with each other properly? Is there anything that needs to be configured? Or will they just communicate normally as it would have been without docker?

Comment: @Rakmo - As far as I know, Docker does not introduce any extra impediments.  Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: I'll be testing it out this week. Once successful, I'll mark this as correct, also please include the above comment in the answer :) ty

Comment: @Rakmo- Done.  (I added a minor note about port numbers.)

Answer (score 4):

Highly available services are *never* built with just two nodes. You **need** at least three, for split brain problem mitigation. In the geographically distributed case this problem is even more important than for physically co-located services; don't try to ignore it if you ever value your data and uptime. If you can't afford three nodes, better don't do any HA at all, or your attempts to get better service will make things worse instead.

Having established that, I suggest you to use Galera. It's multi-master replication built into modern MariaDB (a MySQL clone by the same author, a drop-in replacement). As expected, it requires three nodes, but of these only two must be full-blown servers, and a third one could be so called arbitration node (designed to be just tie-breaker in a quorum selection process).

So you make two containers containing data, and third machine to be an arbiter. Also you can make third node to be a full-blown server, but only use it to take database backups, so primary servers will not get choked at times when backup is running. And you then better set it to be a preferred SST source, so if one server restarts and needs SST, it'll not choke other one during SST process. It is important to have third node in the third place, not to be co-located with two primary servers, so it could be true tie-breaker.

I run such geographically distrubuted Galera setup, MariaDB instances are communicating via VPNs and it performs well.

Comment: 1. I'm not asking for HA. It's for DR.
2. The description clearly states that I do not want 3rd Party Software as an answer.

Comment: I feel your description tends more to HA than DR in its original meaning: a predefined scenario who and what does in which sequence if something goes wrong, it's more of organisational and bureaucracy (in a good sense) thing than technical. Also it doesn't matter: the replication data integrity measures are always done this way, no matter for which purpose. Also, Galera is not more "third party" than, say, InnoDB; it is supplied by default with standard MariaDB distrubution, which itself is supplied with any modern Linux, your container likely already uses it instead of Oracle MySQL.

Comment: Sure. Galera sounds new to me. Thanks for providing a new direction to look into. As of now I'm at a POC stage. I'll get back to mark the correct answer whichever fits the best :)

Comment: @Rakmo did you manage to do replication between multi-server docker containers by using Galera cluster? If yes could you please post the answer how to do it?

Comment: I managed to do it without using Galera. Just some tweaks in MySQL config,